# How to reset the shipping address paypal while checkout?

Tags: paypal, checkout, express-checkout

I'm integrating PayPal into my web application. Here I want to make complete checkout process.It has direct payment and express checkout.

```
In Express checkout we need only PayPal account like 

1)Clicking Check out with PayPal
2) Logs into PayPal to authenticate
3)Reviews the transaction on PayPal
4)Confirms the order and pays from your site
5)Receives an order confirmation 

In Direct checkout(A generic checkout flow),
1)Checks out from the shopping cart page
2)Provides shipping information
3)Chooses a payment option and provides
4)billing and payment information
5)Reviews the order and pays
6)Receives an order confirmation
```

This the flow. In Direct checkout when you choose payment option as PayPal(step 3) you need to login and make payment. Any way there is one default shipping address available in PayPal account and also you must give shipping address in step 2.

Now I want to send the complete cart details and shipping address to PayPal?
and I want make the direct checkout(A generic checkout flow) here? Can any one help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Express Checkout and DoDirectPayment (Website Payments Pro). Express Checkout gives you the redirect-to-PayPal-and-login functionality, whereas DoDirectPayment allows you to take card payments directly on your site.
In addition, you can override the PayPal Profile shipping address of the buyer by specifying ADDROVERRIDE=1 in the SetExpressCheckout API call. Remember you'll need to pass in the appropriate shipping address details information as well.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout